# Hide web menu on inappbrowser

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

Good day everyone. I am using in-appbrowser to open a specific page on my website, but I want my web menu to be hiden when it opens, don't want the menu to show.

[image]

I want it to open only content without the menu like this

[image]

Please I need your help thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As per the official plugin [documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser#inappbrowserinsertcss), you can try inserting a custom css to the window after it has been loaded.

```
const ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_blank');
ref.show();
ref.on('loadstop').subscribe(() => {
    ref.insertCSS({ code: 'header{ display: none !important;}' });
});
```